# How to capture choice from a list nested with a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am loading an HTML page which dynamically populates the result of a search (for a book) in a set of lists attached to a radio button. The user is to choose which book in particular they are looking for from the set of lists by selecting the radio button and clicking "Submit".

How do I capture the ISBN from the list for the radio button that the user selects? Code below.

```
<form id="user_choice" action="/search" method="post">
      {% for data in data %}
          <div class="form-group">    
              <input type="radio" value="book_choice" id="choice" onClick="userSelection(document.getElementById('choice').value">
                  <ul>
                     <li> ISBN: {{ data[0] }} </li>
                     <li> Title: {{ data[1] }} </li>
                     <li> Author: {{ data[2] }} </li>
                     <li> Year: {{ data[3] }} </li>
                  </ul>
          </div>
          <br>    
      {% endfor %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="submitUserSelection()">Select</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Pass the ISBNs into the value of each radio input. Then you can just get the value of the selected input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already grabbing the value of the radio on click, you can change the value attribute to be the books ISBN. Ex:

```
<form id="user_choice" action="/search" method="post">
        {% for data in data %}
            <div class="form-group">    
                <input type="radio" value="{{ data[0] }}" onClick="userSelection(this.value)">
                    <ul>
                        <li>ISBN: {{ data[0] }}</li>
                        <li>Title: {{ data[1] }}</li>
                        <li>Author: {{ data[2] }}</li>
                        <li>Year: {{ data[3] }}</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <br>    
        {% endfor %}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="submitUserSelection()">Select</button>
    </form>
```

I also removed the repeated id since you never want to have duplicate id's

Comment: Thank you!  And yes - I didn't intend to have duplicate id's, thanks for catching.